# setOffscreenPageLimit doesn't load next pages, only keeps previous ones

Tags: android, android-viewpager

That's the behaviour I'm getting on a Galaxy S3, sdk version 17.
Previously visited pages do stay loaded according to the parameter passed to setOffscreenPageLimit but the next page will only load after I start scrolling towards it, regardless of the parameter.

How can I make it pre-load next pages?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what parameter you set this attribute on viewPager, it should still load next page. But it may not REload that page, if it is in given size. For example if you say setOffScreenPageLimit(3) and if you have 3 pages, then all 3 of them will be loaded only once and then they will never get loads again. (Unless you manuelly refresh them)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fragment adapter (and even if you aren't) there's nothing stopping you from instantiating any number of fragments that you'd like to do the preload that you'd like and store them in your adapter.